# Java EL: Access nested properties

Tags: java, jsf, el

Given a class `A`:

```
public class A {
    private String foo;

    //getter, setters etc...

}
```

can one reference the `foo` property if an `A` object itself is exposed as property in a managed bean, e.g:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SomeBean {
    private A a;

    //getter, setters etc...

}
```

`#{someBean.a.foo}`

Comment: Yes, just like that. As long as you have the getters you can access properties in sequence. That EL expression is the equivalent of doing `someBeanInstance.getA().getFoo()` in a class.

Comment: @Gamb whats about modifying `foo`? Will the corresponding code look like `someBeanInstance.getA().setFoo("Hello world")`?

Comment: Something like `<h:inputText value="#{someBean.a.foo}" />`? It'll work too. Did you try it?.

Comment: @Gamb No, actually I wanted to have that expected behaviour to be verified before writing any view/jsf related code. Im currently heavily redesigning my application making tests etc. kind of cumbersome. But due to your comments my question seems to be answered. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Gamb note that it will work only if `someBean.a` is not null.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You're right. I was assuming that but it indeed is something to take into account and make explicit. My bad.

Comment: @Gamb don't be afraid and post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it will work. Both for setting and obtaining the value. An input such as:

```
<h:inputText value="#{someBean.a.foo}" />
```

will both obtain the value to display it and set the new defined value by doing either

```
beanInstance.getA().getFoo();
```

or

```
beanInstance.getA().setFoo("newValue");
```

Just take into account that for this to work and avoid getting a `NullPointerException`, `getA()` cannot return `null`, meaning that your `a` object must be instantiated.